# If $D\subset \Bbb R^p$ dense and f is a continuous function such that it cancels out in D, then f=0

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I just wanted to show you my proof in order to check if i am correct or not, or if a am making big assumptions about certain stuff.

---

Being f a continuous function such that cancels out in D, a dense set. Then it follows that:
\begin{align*}
   &\ \lim_{x\to v}f(x)=f(v)=0-\forall v\in D\subset \Bbb R^p
   \\
  =&\ \lim_{h\to 0}f(v+h)=f(v)=0-\forall v\in D\subset \Bbb R^p
\end{align*}
Lets suppose that $f(x)\neq 0$. Then, it exists an $x_o \in \Bbb R^p$ such that 
\begin{align*}
   &\ \lim_{h\to 0}f(x_o+h)=f(x_o)\neq0
\end{align*}
Then lets take an A$\subset \Bbb R^p$ and A being dense in $R^p$, in which $x_o\in A$. So, because D and A are dense then the union both are dense, then we have that $x_o\in A\cup D$ and from the hypothesis we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
   &\ \lim_{h\to 0}f(x_o+h)=f(x_o)=0
\end{align*}
That is a contradiction from the assumption that it was not zero. Then f(x)=0 for all x in $\Bbb R^p$.

---

My idea is that it doesn't matter which subset of $\Bbb R^p$ you take, you can always find a bigger subset that is dense and contains the one you propose, and from the hypothesis it would conclude that it is zero.

---

*Also I don't completely understand why it needs to be a continuous function, maybe because the only functions that cancel out elements from a certain vectorial space are always continuous? I would like some ideas about why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $|f(x_0)|\ne 0$ then $|f(x_0)|>\epsilon>0$ on a neighborhood of $x_0$

But $D$ is dense, so you can find a point $x_1$ in the neighborhood that belongs to $D$, so $f(x_1)=0$ contradiction.

A direct way: for $x\in \mathbb R^n$ construct the sequence $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subset D$, $x_n\rightarrow x$ by choosing $x_n$ in the ball centered in $x$ and of radius $1/n$.

Then $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=0$

Answer (score 0):

For your last question: Consider the function that's zero on the rationals and 1 on the irrationals. It's zero on a dense set, but not zero everywhere. Hence continuity is necessary.

As a more extreme case, consider the function on the reals that's zero everywhere except at $\pi$, where it takes the value $1$.

Answer (score 0):

One of many equivalent def'ns of the continuity of a function $f:X\to Y$ is that whenever $A\subset X$ and $p\in cl_X(A)$ we have $f(p)\in cl_Y(\{f(a):a\in A\}).$  More briefly, $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff  $$\forall A\subset X\;(\; f(cl_X(A))\subset cl_Y(f(A)\;).$$ In particular if $f$ is continuous and $f(A)=\{0\}$ then $f(cl_X(A)\}\subset cl_B(\{0\}).$

When $B=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology we have $cl_B(\{0\}=\{0\}.$ So if $A$ is dense in $X$ and $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, with $f(A)=\{0\},$  then $$\{0\}\subset f(X)=f(cl_X(A))\subset cl_{\mathbb R}f(A)=cl_{\mathbb R}\{0\}=\{0\}.$$